# how to integrate third party installation along with current installer in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to install visual c++ 2013 along with my installer in wix. 
for that i am using custom installation like

```
<Binary Id="vcredist_x862013.exe" SourceFile="D:\Projects\vcredist_x862013.exe"/>
<CustomAction Id="Launchvc2013" BinaryKey="vcredist_x862013.exe"  ExeCommand="" Execute='deferred' Return='asyncNoWait' Impersonate='no'/>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='Launchvc2013' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

currently if the user installs or didnt install vc2013 as part of installation the setup will continue.

is it possible to make it like, the set up should fail if user cancel visual c++ installtion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible, you need to use bootstrapper for that.

Use [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications/) by Heath Stewart to get you started.